# (How) can I conditionally center a div (horizontally) based on the size of its previous sibling

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I have a grid with two columns. The first is a sidebar that the user can hide/show and the second is the main content. Here's what that looks like...

**sidebar shown**
[image]

**sidebar hidden**
[image]

I would like to use CSS (tailwind, specifically) to horizontally center the main content iff the sidebar is hidden.

### Code

```
<div className="w-full grid grid-cols-[auto_1fr]">
  <MySidebarComponent />
  <MyMainComponent />
</div>
```

#### Question

Is this possible / how can I make this work? I thought that tailwind's new [`has` variant](https://tailwindcss.com/blog/tailwindcss-v3-4#new-has-variant) might help, but I couldn't get it to work.

#### Note

My sidebar has a property that changes based on its open/closed state. Note that this is based on [Headless UI's Disclosure component](https://headlessui.com/react/disclosure).

**open state**

```
<div data-headlessui-state="open">
  <div>Other contents here...</div>
</div>
```

**closed state**

```
<div data-headlessui-state></div>  // No contents
```

#### Playground

[A place to tinker](https://play.tailwindcss.com/7MeEoCpjJX)

Comment: if you have something in state that is tracking if the nav is open, then you can use that to add a class to the `<MainContent>` which would toggle a class that you use to change position it (like make it `display: flex`, `align-items: center`) or something like that.  or you can add that class to the parent element and change the columns to just 1 with the content centered.  Point being - one way to do it would be a conditional class you can manipulate

Comment: @HolyMoly Thanks, I know how to solve this using state, but I wanted to look for a pure CSS solution first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use tailwinds [`peer`](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/hover-focus-and-other-states#styling-based-on-sibling-s) modifier, which also has support to [style based on data attribute](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/hover-focus-and-other-states#data-attributes).

```
<div className="w-full grid grid-cols-[auto_1fr]">
    <div className="border border-blue-500 peer" data-headlessui-state="open">Sidebar</div>
    <div className="border border-red-500 peer-data-[headlessui-state='open']:text-left text-center">Main content</div>
</div>
```

Here is a [working example](https://play.tailwindcss.com/DsLszIsMXZ)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a [pure CSS solution](https://play.tailwindcss.com/SzPXmhpDXp?file=css) that I did using the playground using a ['Next-sibling combinator'](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Next-sibling_combinator) that selects the main content div if the state of side nav is "open".